# Check if popUntil possible / Check if named route in navigation stack

Tags: flutter

How can I check if there is a route with name `workout` in my navigation stack? Whenever I call `popUntil` and the route is not in my stack, I get:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator-[GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState> _WidgetsAppState#9d229](dirty, state: NavigatorState#86712(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2330 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp 
lib/main.dart:58
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      NavigatorState.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2330
#3      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4334
```

I have tried this but `popUntil` still throws the exception

```
          try {
            Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('workout'));
          } catch (e) {
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_context) => WorkoutPage(),
                settings: RouteSettings(name: 'workout'),
                fullscreenDialog: true
              ));
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on clearing the entire stack and showing a specific screen, you should try the below code:

Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/screen4', (Route route) => false);

It should do the work.